# None : output in function forward

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I got no output after computing `forward`. I succed to print X, `print(X)` which is different from `None`, but when I put X in `Y=[np.transpose(X)]` and call it in `sigmoid(np.dot(W[i], Y[i])+B[i])` it becomes `None`. W and B are ok, sigmoid works. What is wrong with Y?

```
def forward(sigmoid,W,B,X):

    Y,Yp = [np.transpose(X)],[]
    for i in range(len(W)-1):
---->   F, Fp = sigmoid(np.dot(W[i], Y[i])+B[i]) # problem is here Y is none
        Y = Y.append(F)
        Yp= Yp.append(Fp)

    return Y,Yp
```

This is my function:

```
def sigmoid(z):

    # z is a float
    y=np.divide(1,1+np.exp(-z))
    yp= y*(1-y)
    return y,yp
```

I can't see what is wrong here ?

Comment: The expression in that line includes `Y[i]` and `B[i]`.  Check if either `Y` or `B` is `None`.

Comment: the error is being caused `Y[i]` or `B[i]` and has nothing to do with `sigmoid(z)`

Comment: l updated my  post

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
Y = Y.append(F)
Yp= Yp.append(Fp)
```

Both `Y` and `Yp` are lists and therefore `.append` works in-place so these lists are updated. But the `.append` itself returns `None` so in the second iteration of your loop you're not working with the lists anymore.

Use:

```
Y.append(F)
Yp.append(Fp)
```

instead.

This small snippet shows the difference:

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = a.append(2)

>>> print(a)
[1, 2]
>>> print(b)
None
```